# C++ Does File Scope Become Global to Entire Program on Compile?

Tags: c++, scope

As I understand it (and I may be incorrect), when a program is compiled all of the source files are merged into one massive swath of code. At this stage can the entire program "see" the content of every other file's scope?

Here is a really simple example:

1.cpp

```
int X = 0;
```

2.cpp

```
string Y = "";
```

Is it safe to assume that 1.cpp will never see Y and 2.cpp will never see X? That is they can be anything and never conflict or cause issues?

Comment: I have discovered a remarkable proof that they are visible to each other, but this comment box is too small to contain it :-)

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, at least in the general case.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: I am still learning C++, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As I understand it (and I may be incorrect), when a program is compiled all of the source files are merged into one massive swath of code.

No. compilation takes place in *translation units*. A `.cpp` file will be compiled at a time. All of it's `#include`d headers will be literally copied into the file, but the result will be compiled separately from other `.cpp`s in your program. They are all then *linked* together at the end. This is when all the symbols and names are matched up.

If you declare your variables just like that, at "file scope", they **will** be visible to the rest of the program (although you need a declaration in the other file to actually use it. This is why the declaration would typically go in a header file). If you want *translation unit* scope, with no visibility outside and no risk of name clash, declare them inside an unnamed namespace:

```
// File 1
namespace {
    int X = 0;
}
```

and

```
// File 1
namespace {
    float X = 0.0; // No clash!
}
```

(Bear in mind that any actual implementation may do things it's own way with regard to compiling and linking, but I think I've described a reasonably typical model that you can pretend is true for thinking about most simple cases.)

Comment: Shouldn't `static` keyword in cpp file do the same?

Comment: That's about linkage not visibility. Both are important factors.

Comment: @Samuel Yes, exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, but that usage is deprecated in favour of unnamed namespaces, even in the 2003 Standard: "[namespace.unnamed] 2 The use of the `static` keyword is deprecated when declaring objects in a namespace scope (see annex D); the *unnamed-namespace* provides a superior alternative."

Comment: @BoBTFish `static` is still useful in some cases.  I use it a lot, for example, when interfacing to Python; the functions must be `extern "C"`, which means the namespace (including the unnamed namespace) are ignored (practically, anyway), so `static` is the only means of ensuring that they aren't visible in other translation units.

Comment: As for implementations possibly doing things in another way: they must behave "as if" linking were a separate step after compilation, see the phases of translation in the standard.  (But while linking really is a separate phase in almost all implementations, most do fuse some of the earlier phases---and have a separate code generation phase which isn't mentioned in the standard.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, thank you; I wasn't sure how to describe exactly what is required under the *as-if* rule.

Comment: @BoBTFish No, it _was_ deprecated, but that hasn't been the case for quite some time. C++11 undeprecated it because it's a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would cause any problems unless you have both these .cpp files precompiled.  Only pre compiled headers are made global(unless you don't modify the make file).

Answer (score 0):

In your example X and Y do not conflict with each other because they are different identifies. The both variables are defined in the global namespace and have external linkage. 
Of course 1.cpp will not see Y until Y will be declared in 1.cpp.

For example

**1.cpp**

```
extern string Y;
```

This is a declaration of the variable Y. It is not a definition. So the linker will consider this Y and Y in 2.cpp as the same one object.

However if you will define Y in 1.cpp for example as

**1.cpp**

```
int Y;
```

or even as

**1.cpp**

```
string Y;
```

then the linker will issue an error because it will find two definitions of objects with the same name with external linkage. And it will not know what definition to use.

At the same time you could define variable Y in 1.cpp as having internal linkage. For example

**1.cpp**

```
static string Y;
```

or

**1.cpp**

```
namespace
{
    string Y;
}
```

In both cases variable Y will have internal linkage. in thjis case this definition of Y will not conflict with the definition of Y in 2.cpp because variable Y in 1.cpp will not be seen outside 1.cpp. It will not be placed in the table of variables with external linkage and the linker will know nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no such thing as file scope in C++.  What you
probably mean is global scope, which is just a special case of
namespace scope.

And you have to distinguish between visibility and binding: the
first determines what symbols you can access at a given place in
the source code; the second determines what entity a symbol
binds to.  Within a given translation unit, you can never "see"
a symbol which was not declared in that translation unit, in
some way or another.  In that sense, if you have `int X;` in one
source file (`1.cpp`), and do not declare `X` in another source
file (`2.cpp`), including in any headers included in the other
source file, then `X` is not visible in the other source file.
On the other hand, if you do accidentally try to define another
entity named `X` in the second source file, the symbol will
refer to the same entity as in the first source file; in the
case where both declarations define a variable (as in your
example), that is undefined behavior.

Because such undefined behavior can so easily occur
unintentionally, you usually will not want to define variables
(or other entities) in the global namespace unless you want them
to be visible everywhere (in which case, you will put the
appropriate declaration in a header).  If you want the defined
symbol to only be visible in a single translation unit, you will
put it in unnamed namespace (which in fact has a magic name
which is unique for each translation unit).